# CakePHP Bake :: Create Element file on bake command

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cake-bake

I've created a plug-in, and inside that plug-in I've got a custom bake template. I'd like to create an Element file `_head.ctp` inside the `/src/Template/Element/` folder when I execute the bake command.

The element file will consist of a code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-block">
        <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(array('action' => 'add', '_ext' => 'html')); ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus-circle2 position-left"></i> Add</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(array('action' => 'index', '_ext' => 'html')); ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon icon-grid2 position-left"></i> List All <?= __('{{ pluralHumanName }}') ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bake command which I'm using is: `bin\cake bake all Customers --prefix backend --theme MyBakeTheme`

**NOTE:** Once I'll execute this command my Element file `_head.ctp` should create inside the `/src/Template/Element/Customer` folder.

CakePHP v3.8.2 and Bake v1.x.

Can someone please assist in how I can create a custom Element file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll probably have to provide some more information in order for someone to give a good answer. For example elaborate on what exactly this element file is used for, what exactly it contains (does is require access to variables, etc), and on what kind of bake task you'd need to create it.

Comment: Add more information with-in my initial message.

Comment: You have to create a Customer named folder inside Element then you should run this command. bin\cake bake all customers --prefix Foldername.